# array to bitmap in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

I'd like to create a bitmap by turning an array into a bitmap. First I create the bitmap from the data:

```
BITMAPINFO info;
info.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
info.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
info.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
info.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
info.bmiHeader.biHeight = -height(windowSize);
info.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
info.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
info.bmiHeader.biWidth = width(windowSize);
info.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 100;
info.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 100;
Gdiplus::Bitmap *b = new Bitmap(&info, (void *)field);
```

And then I try to draw it on the screen, but it only contains black:

```
Gdiplus::Graphics *graphics = new Gdiplus::Graphics(hdc);
...
graphics->DrawImage(<pointer to bitmap>, 0, 0);
```

The array currently contains 32 bits of data per pixel, 8 bits for each component. The red component is shifted 24 bits to the left, green is shifted 16 bits to the left and blue is shifted 8 bits to the left.

I can assure you that the field array contains data in which the colors aren't all black. Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your pixel format is wrong; 32bpp leaves the top byte of each pixel unused but you're leaving the bottom byte unused.  However, unless your image is all red you should still see something.

Comment: @arx thanks for pointing that out. But is red or blue the most significant byte?

Comment: Also I'm just getting garbage memory :/

Comment: Your colors would be messed up but you would still see something.  Since you're not the problem is probably elsewhere.  Anyway, I think each DWORD is 00BBGGRR.  And does Gdi+ expect transparency information?  If it does you'd want AABBGGRR.

Comment: You need to set the top bits to FF to say "opaque". so red is 0xFFFF0000, Green is 0xFF00FF00 and Blue is 0xFF0000FF.

Answer (score 0):

Does the field array last for the whole lifetime of your image? Bitmap constructors that take a pointer to image data will actually store a reference to that data, rather than copying it.

If you want to copy your data and have it stored in the Bitmap object, use NULL for the image bits (or use a constructor that does not require a pointer to image bits), and use the Bitmap.LockBits function to fill in the data. You don't have to copy the bits manually; just fill in the BitmapData structure and use the ImageLockModeWrite|ImageLockModeUserInputBuf flags, and GDI+ will copy the bits by itself.

You may also have better luck with the Bitmap(INT,INT,INT,PixelFormat,BYTE*) constructor (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as it gives you more direct control over how GDI+ will interpret the data (including making it obvious whether your data contains alpha information).